# How can I make this MongoDB query more efficient?

Tags: .net, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver, nosql

Just a simple query looking at a list of objects passed in  and finding values that match. AObjects is a List of AObjects.

```
var queries = AObjects
    .Select(g =>
        Query.And(
            Query<BObject>.EQ(m => m.SourceKey, g.SourceKey),
            Query<BObject>.EQ(m => m.SourceTypeId, g.SourceTypeId)
        )
    )
    .ToList();

var query = Query.Or(queries);

var result = Collection.Find(query).ToList();

return result;
```

Right now when I run this query with a large set of AObjects (2500,7500) the query takes an extremely long time; 1 and 8 minutes respectively.

Both SourceKey and SourceTypeId are indexed for the BObject's collection.

I feel there should be a better way to build this query to make it more efficient, but I'm somewhat of a noob when it comes to NoSQL query optimization.

Thanks.

Comment: The first thing about mongoDB query optimization you need to know is how to use [.explain()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/).

Answer (score 1):

`MongoDB` (like most databases) can't use more than a single index at a time (unless it's an `Or` query). That means that although you maintain 2 indexes only 1 will be chosen and used.

To build an index for that specific query you need a compound index of both `"SourceKey"` and `"SourceTypeId"`:

```
AObjects.CreateIndex(IndexKeys<AObject>.Ascending(_ => _.SourceKey).Ascending(_ => _.SourceTypeId)
```

Comment: Does this suggestion assume that AObjects is a mongo entity?  Right now it's just an object in memory, a List of AObject.

Comment: @BigDubb use the type you store in the collection. AObject in this case.

Comment: I cant create an index on a List of BObject.  I did look at my indicies on the collection.  Looks like the key is a compound key on the collection.   {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "SourceKey" : 1,
            "SourceTypeId" : 1
        },
        "unique" : true,
        "ns" : "mytool.BObjects",
        "name" : "SourceKey_1_SourceTypeId_1"

Answer (score 1):

I ended up changing how the query is built.

Rather than rely on the code to build the query, I just built the json myself.

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("{ $or:[");
geographies.ToList().ForEach(x =>
{
    var s = "{ " + string.Format("SourceKey:\"{0}\", SourceTypeId: {1} ", x.SourceKey, x.SourceTypeId) + " },";
    sb.Append(s);
});

sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);
sb.Append("]}");

BsonDocument query = MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(sb.ToString());

var result = Collection.FindAs<MapGeography>(qDoc).ToList();

return result;
```

Just ran some tests.

2629 items used to take 1:02.249, now takes 0:26.566 
6364 items used to take 6:07.900, now takes 2:40.868

Not ideal, i'd like to get this running quicker, but this will work for now.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense that it took 4 minutes just to build the query; even with 6300 `$or` elements this is unreasonable. If you're sure this is the case (you can easily find out by measuring the time it takes to build the query vs. the time it takes to run it) then you should probably submit this as a bug to the MongoDB C# driver project.

Comment: It wasn't the query building that took long, I tested this to see what that was taking, for 6k elements it tool 13 seconds to output to a logger the .explain(true) on the query.

Comment: If so, then this answer saying "I changed how the query is built and this improved performance" is not entirely accurate.

Could you edit your question and include the output of `.explain()` on this query?

Comment: the explain on 2k objects it far too large to add here.